# Hooking Windows SSL libraries

Tags: tls, windows, client

What libraries does Windows use to send ssl traffic? The ws2_32.dll has the tcp send function, but the traffic is encrypted before it reaches that function.

I'm looking to reach the code where the traffic is still in plaintext. Its a windows application as well, its not a web page so I can't look at firefox source code etc.

There is a tool called Echo Mirage that does it, but I'm interested in how they achieve that.

Thanks

Comment: If it's an http application hooking wininet or Winhttp might be easier.

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses its Secure Channel (`schannel.dll`) for all SSL/TLS type communications.  You can try to look at the [Windows docs for TLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380516(v=vs.85).aspx).  You might also be able to use [Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler) as an SSL proxy to look at the decrypted data.

@CBHacking commented with a tool that is very useful, [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226).  It uses Fiddler behind the scenes when you use its *Quick Trace* Tool for live HTTP decryption.  But you can also perform [Post Decryption on TLS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/messageanalyzer/2014/10/21/post-decryption-of-tlsssl-traffic/) using this tool.  A quote from that blog post:

> Today you can capture the traffic before it is encrypted using the
>   Unencrypted HTTPS scenario from the Quick Trace menu. This requires
>   you install the Fiddler Core components, which is how we enable this
>   scenario. However, there are some limitations and scenarios that it
>   doesn’t cover, like non HTTP traffic. And not all clients and
>   capturing scenarios work with Fiddler. So another other option is to
>   decrypt after the fact.
>
> Post decryption has its challenges too. You need the private cert and
>   password, which might not always be easily available. However, one
>   nice mitigation is that the person who does have access to the
>   certificate can always save the results, filtered down, and send only
>   that data he wants you to see. Also, we haven’t hooked up every parser
>   yet, however for some cases it’s a simple change and something we’ll
>   extend moving forward.

If you have access to the cert in which you want to use for your application, then this could be a good substitution for non-HTTP TLS traffic.

Comment: You can also use [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) to view TLS traffic, although (much like Fiddler) it's just adding a trusted root cert and then intercepting the handshake, injecting a MitM cert with a known private key, and decrypting the traffic on the fly. Won't work for apps that use cert pinning, for example.

Comment: @CBHacking That's a very nifty tool.  Even if you wanted to have your app use cert pinning you could easily enable that later, and use this for protocol verification.  Nice find!